# How to fully use 20GB cache SSD, preinstalled win from acer

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

i buy acer laptop with 500GB HDD + 20 GB SSD.

I can't install OS on SSD, because its too small. So how can i fully use that SSD disk?

The things i now:

- **Intel Rapid Start Technology** - its configured and i think its working. But it only works in OS booting, right? Now i have 0% of usage while running.
- **Intel Smart Response Technology** - I dont have "raid" option in BIOS, only AHCI :( so i cant use that.
- **Virtual memory** - also cant use, because there is no partition on SSD.

Any other idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really is too small to be of much use, install your favourite games or applications on there, you might notice slightly faster loading times.

Comment: thanks for reply! :) But i cant put data there. There is no partition, its marked as "hibernation parition" because of that smart start technology.

Comment: You could just write over that partition, but then you won't be able to hibernate your laptop.

Comment: yeah, i know. But i would rather speed up OS than games :)

Comment: Then make the whole thing a 20GB Pagefile.

You are trying to get more out of a crappy SSD than it's worth, at that size the Read/Write speeds are probably terrible and have little advantage over the HDD you're using anyway.

Comment: I think, thats best solution... But why they put that SSD there? What is its purpose? Only for sleep/hibernation and quicker start? Thanks a lot!

Comment: On a laptop, you need to hibernate rather than sleep as sleep requires a small amount of energy (Which drains your battery). Hibernate however requires to write the contents of the RAM to disk which uses a partition/file as large as your RAM. Whilst you probably don't have 20GB of RAM, it was most likely the smallest SSD Acer could get.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the SSD is a cache drive.  The system should be monitoring what you are using from the spinning platter hard drive and depending on what gets used most - move that to the cache drive so reads come from the SSD, not the HDD.  Eventually the most used boot portion of the OS and some apps end up there.

Comment: I think that too, but i am looking at task manager at performace tab and when i work (opening programs and stuff) there is always 0% of usage of that disk.

Comment: only way to do SSD as cache drive is to use Intel Smart Response Technology, and i think my motherboard dont support it :(